# How do I prevent a subdirectory from being matched in .gitignore?

Tags: git

I have a project directory that includes the following:

```
log/
src/log/
tests/log/
.gitignore
```

In my .gitignore file, I added the following line, thinking it would just ignore the top-level `log/`:

```
log/
```

However, it also seems to ignore `src/log` and `tests/log`. How can I prevent it from doing that?

Comment: @MattMcNabb The first code block is my directory structure. The second code block is what's actually in my .gitignore file.

Comment: @Evan yeah, I realized that just after commenting. I guess the other answerer also made the same error!

Comment: @closers this is asking about ensuring that a .gitignore line matches only the top-level directory and leaves subdirectories alone. It's not about ignoring everything, then whitelisting subdirectories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `/log/` instead; this means it will only ignore directory `log` which occurs at the top level of your project.

Comment: Blah, I knew it was something stupid I was blanking on. Thanks! (Will accept when it lets me)